# How can I use a Date object and a string with a day name to create a new Date object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a Date object

```
Mon, 03 Dec 2012
```

and I have a String that contains a day name

```
"Thursday"
```

How can I use those two objects to find a new Date object representing the day name in the same week as the original Date object? So for this example, it would be

```
Thu, 07 Dec 2012
```

In this scenario, a week goes from Monday to Sunday.

I'm using Rails 3.2.0 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can manage to convert "Thursday" to week day 4 -- I know you can --, you can get another date like this:

```
1.9.3p125 :014 > d = Date.parse "Mon, 03 Dec 2012"
 => Mon, 03 Dec 2012 
1.9.3p125 :015 > Date.commercial d.cwyear, d.cweek, 4
 => Thu, 06 Dec 2012 
1.9.3p125 :016 >
```

BTW, you can store the map from day name to number in an Array or an Hash, or use I18n.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a better way for doing this but you could do

```
def date_by_day(date, day_name)
  beginning_of_week = date.beginning_of_week
  7.times do |i|
    _date = beginning_of_week + i.days
    return _date if _date.strftime("%A") == day_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will work nicely for you.

```
def date_by_day(date, day_name)
  beginning_of_week = date.beginning_of_week
  day_number = Time::DAYS_INTO_WEEK[day_name.to_sym]
  return (beginnig_of_week + day_number.days)
end
```